# Multi-regional/multilingual hosting

Tags: redirects, web-hosting, dns, multilingual, multi-subdomains

I'm looking for ways to achieve a Multi-regional/multilingual hosting of static type website(s) that'll cover different countries.

Let's called the domain example.com for now.

I've read the Google Advanced SEO guide, but certain elements are unclear.

My understanding is that example.com redirects to example.com/de/ if one is located in Germany, or example.com/es/ if located in Spain and so on. A must would be to be able to select locale for the language used (Englishman in Spain for example).

Ideally I want a common layout (logo, palette, font and styling), but the main content will be administered by the content-master in the respective country (text/images/contact info etc...).

And in regards to email support, what's the best way to solve that issue? E.g. lars@de.example.com or jose@es.example.com? I want every country to be in charge of their own email-service.

Ideally I want the use of a web-builder (for simplicity), not Wordpress. I've contacted Squarespace and One.com, but have not yet got any response from either of them.

Comment: Are you aiming to achieve a multi-lingual *multi-regional* site, or just a multi-lingual site? There is an important distinction. A multi-lingual site presents information in different languages, a multi-regional site targets users in different physical locations for sales that can only be done regionally due to distance or legal constraints. Users should never be targeted for language solely by region if possible, they can be targeted for language based on their own language preference as specified by their browser (`Accept-Language` header).

Comment: Questions asking for recommended external websites, tools, resources, and software are off-topic..

Comment: @KarlAndresen It's a little unclear, but it appears you're asking multiple questions here, with one possibly being for a website builder recommendation. Please edit your question to remove the later, and so that it's only asking one distinguishable question.